# leading 0 not displaying in mysql table result

Tags: php, mysql

just concatenating two values to one column in a mysql table. First Value from mysql table and second value from PHP constant saved as `define('ACCOUNTCODESUFFIX','016');`.

**MySql query somewhat looks like**

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(\' \', mbrs.firstname, mbrs.lastname) AS fullname, 
       CONCAT_WS(\'-\',gl.code, '.ACCOUNTCODESUFFIX.') AS code 
FROM allTbls 
    INNER JOIN generalledgertbl gl ON (allTbls.claim_type=gl.claimtype 
                                AND allTbls.claim_category=gl.claimtitle 
                                AND allTbls.claimoption=gl.claimoption)
```

**Output:**

```
fullname |  code

name1 | 12345-16

name2 | 23456-16
```

> How to have Output like this without using `LPAD()`

```
fullname |  code

name1 | 12345-016

name2 | 23456-016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it, and without all that escaping that is probably causing the confusion

```
define('ACCOUNTCODESUFFIX','016');

$sql = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', mbrs.firstname, mbrs.lastname) AS fullname, 
       CONCAT_WS('-',gl.code, '" . ACCOUNTCODESUFFIX . "') AS code 
        FROM allTbls 
            INNER JOIN generalledgertbl gl ON (allTbls.claim_type=gl.claimtype 
                                AND allTbls.claim_category=gl.claimtitle 
                                AND allTbls.claimoption=gl.claimoption)";

echo $sql;
```

RESULT:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', mbrs.firstname, mbrs.lastname) AS fullname, 
       CONCAT_WS('-',gl.code, '016') AS code 
        FROM allTbls 
            INNER JOIN generalledgertbl gl ON (allTbls.claim_type=gl.claimtype 
                                AND allTbls.claim_category=gl.claimtitle 
                                AND allTbls.claimoption=gl.claimoption)
```

Comment: You fancy pants, you.

Comment: They are pretty fancy, thanks for noticing. @Fred-ii-